# Developing page that request basic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm beginner to asp.net and have been asked to develop a page that request a basic authentication. when the user click on the link, log in screen (dialog) will pop-up. after the user filling the user name and the password, the requested http header will be shown with the encrypted user name and password.

I tried everything but I couldn't get it right

here is my code

`code`

```
public partial class Authenticate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://abdullahtk.somee.com");  
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);  


            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "BASIC Realm=My Realm");
            WebResponse v = request.GetResponse();  
            Stream rStream = v.GetResponseStream();  
            StreamReader str = new StreamReader(rStream);  
            if (str.EndOfStream != true)  
            {  
                Response.Write(str.ReadToEnd());  
            }  
            v.Close();  
            rStream.Close();  
            str.Close();  

        }  
}
```

please help me!?

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far? Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want BASIC AUTHENTICATION and not FORMS AUTHENTICATION, you can just configure IIS to use it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009%28v=WS.10%29.aspx

This will work with ASP.NET, PHP, Classic ASP, etc... even plain .HTML!

Comment: I think OP is asking how to develop a page that does basic authentication (i.e., user name/password validation) - not how to use Basic Authentication.  Two different things.

Comment: I tried to do that but I think there is a way to do basic authentication by using Request and Response properties. Is that right?